# Use local directories when installing matplotlib from source

Tags: python, matplotlib, makefile

I installed freetype-2.4.10, libpng-1.5.12, and zlib-1.2.7 into local directories.  Now, in matplotlib I would like to do:

```
python setup.py install
```

When I did this for lxml I did something like:

```
python setup.py install --with-xml2-config=/home/test/libxml2/bin/xml2-config --with-xslt-config=/home/test/libxslt/bin/xslt-config
```

How can I point matplotlib to the proper freetype, libpng and zlib libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `INSTALL` file:

> If you have installed prerequisites to nonstandard places and need to
>   inform matplotlib where they are, edit `setupext.py` and add the
>   base dirs to the `basedir` dictionary entry for your
>   `sys.platform`. e.g., if the header to some required library is in
>   `/some/path/include/someheader.h`, put `/some/path` in the
>   `basedir` list for your platform.